# react native: how to automatically run websocket server when app starts

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io, nodemon

i've integrated socket.io into my react native app and it works successfully. However i always have to start the server manually using nodemon. After running `react-native run-android` i also have to enter `nodemon index.js` from the terminal which contains my socket.io configuration in order to get the server working. I need this server to start automatically whenever the app starts since i plan to build the app and run it on a real device where i cannot execute the nodemon command in a terminal to start the websocket server

Comment: seperate your server project and your client project? then you can maybe use ngrok for your server and debug that way

Comment: @lastpeony4 thanks for the suggestion. I'd look into it and send u the feedback